# FB.login popup is displayed behind main window on OSX+Chrome

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My AngularJs app use Facebook js sdk to connect users.
It work well for the most of browsers/os but the connection popup is displayed behind the main window (where is called the function FB.login) on OSX + google chrome.
It's only happening on OSX + Chrome. (i tested it on 3 OSX with Chrome).

Firefox+OSX = OK, Opera+OSX = OK, Chrome+Linux=OK, Chrome+Windows=OK ...

Is there any way out?

Comment: just try restarting Chrome completely, even chrome apps if they are running in background. some time chrome act wired.

Comment: I restarted each chrome process but nothing change

Comment: I have the same problem. It didn't happen two days ago, but it happens today. It's weird.